# return in span from select

Tags: php, jquery

I have a small school project, that I am working on. In the select menu I can choose a casino, that is registered in my database. That is working fine. But I need to have a span where that name i choose i printed.

PHP working:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="choosecasino" id="rl_select_casino">
      <option>Choose Casino</option>
          <?php
          $sql ="SELECT * FROM casinos ORDER BY name;";
          $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
          //print($res);
          if($res){                                       
              while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                  ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $row['c_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
                  <?php                                           
              }                               
          }
         ?>                                 
</select>
```

JQuery Working:

```
<script>
function showSelectedItem() {
    var item = document.getElementById("selectcasino").value;
    document.getElementById("currentcasino").innerHTML = item;
}

    document.getElementById("selectcasino").addEventListener("change", showSelectedItem);
</script>
```

Select statement I am working on:

```
Casino: <span id="currentcasino">
         <?php
           $sql = "SELECT FROM casinos WHERE name='?'";
           echo $sql;
        ?>
        </span>
```

What do I need more in my sql statement?

Best Regards.

Comment: You have to remove the quotes `'?'`, you have to bind something to the placeholder, you have to execute the query and you have to fetch the results. Other than that ou should be good to go.

Comment: "where that name i choose i printed".  If you just need to print the name, why do you need the second query? You already have the name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Yes I actually only need the name. But how can I print it? I just seems like so much code to make only for printing a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you have tagged this question with the `jquery` tag, I'm going to assume that you have jquery available to you (even though the code that you marked as "JQuery Working" is raw javascript, not jQuery).  If you do, this should work for you.  [Here's a sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2g5b0g6/)

```
<script>
function showSelectedItem() {
    // take the text of the selected option and inject it into the 'currentcasino' span
    $("#currentcasino").html($("#selectcasino option:selected").text());
}

    $("#selectcasino").on("change", showSelectedItem);
</script>
```

You can remove the PHP code from your `currentcasino` span.

If you are *not* using jQuery, it is a bit more convoluted, but can still be done.  [Here's a fiddle for this version](https://jsfiddle.net/hd8m7eqv/)

```
<script>
function showSelectedItem() {
    // take the text of the selected option and inject it into the 'currentcasino' span
    var theSelectedIndex = document.getElementById("selectcasino").selectedIndex;
    var theSelectedText = document.getElementById("selectcasino").options[theSelectedIndex].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("currentcasino").innerHTML(theSelectedText);
}

    document.getElementById("selectcasino").addEventListener("change", showSelectedItem);
</script>
```